# Why does the published contract IDL fail with RPC response error -32002?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, idl, ethereum

So I can create, test locally, and publish my contract to testnet.

Yet when I run

```
anchor idl init --filepath target/idl/getter_examples.json --provider.wallet /keys/id.json --provider.cluster testnet 3EM7KQFdV2V8AyA5ugNdAyrEhmicvdqR68VJ4e21FBsf
```

I get :

```
Error: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid program argument [3 log messages]

Caused by:
    RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid program argument [3 log messages]
```

Here is my contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract getter_examples {
    bool private value = true;

    @payer(payer)
    constructor() {
        print("Hello, World!");
    }

    function flip() public {
            value = !value;
    }

    /// Simply returns the current value of our `bool`.
    function get() public view returns (bool) {
            return value;
    }
    
    function getBlockNumberMod10() public view returns (uint) {
        return block.number % 10;
    }

 
    function getBlockNumberE5Div123() public view returns (uint) {
        return (block.number * 1e5) / 123;
    }

    function getPseudoRandomNumber() public view returns (uint) {
        uint combinedEntropy = uint(block.timestamp) + uint(block.number);

        return combinedEntropy;
    }
}
```

Here is IDL anchor generated for it:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "name": "getter_examples",
  "instructions": [
    {
      "name": "new",
      "accounts": [
        {
          "name": "dataAccount",
          "isMut": true,
          "isSigner": true,
          "isOptional": false
        },
        {
          "name": "payer",
          "isMut": true,
          "isSigner": true,
          "isOptional": false
        },
        {
          "name": "systemProgram",
          "isMut": false,
          "isSigner": false,
          "isOptional": false
        }
      ],
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "name": "flip",
      "docs": [
        "notice: A message that can be called on instantiated contracts.\nThis one flips the value of the stored `bool` from `true`\nto `false` and vice versa."
      ],
      "accounts": [
        {
          "name": "dataAccount",
          "isMut": true,
          "isSigner": false,
          "isOptional": false
        }
      ],
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "name": "get",
      "docs": [
        "notice: Simply returns the current value of our `bool`."
      ],
      "accounts": [
        {
          "name": "dataAccount",
          "isMut": false,
          "isSigner": false,
          "isOptional": false
        }
      ],
      "args": [],
      "returns": "bool"
    },
    {
      "name": "getBlockNumberMod10",
      "accounts": [],
      "args": [],
      "returns": "u256"
    },
    {
      "name": "getBlockNumberE5Div123",
      "accounts": [
        {
          "name": "clock",
          "isMut": false,
          "isSigner": false,
          "isOptional": false
        }
      ],
      "args": [],
      "returns": "u256"
    },
    {
      "name": "getPseudoRandomNumber",
      "accounts": [
        {
          "name": "clock",
          "isMut": false,
          "isSigner": false,
          "isOptional": false
        }
      ],
      "args": [],
      "returns": "u256"
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "address": "3EM7KQFdV2V8AyA5ugNdAyrEhmicvdqR68VJ4e21FBsf"
  }
}
```

my setup is

```
SOLANA_CLI is "v1.18.3"
ANCHOR_CLI is "v0.29.0"
NODE_VERSION is "v18.18.0"
```

How can I publish the IDL for a solidity-based contract on testnet in Solana?